# Cannot run python.exe from PyCharm: requires elevation

Tags: pycharm, python-3.6

I use the PyCharm IDE for Python development and today I was trying to run a very simple program and got an error stating:

> "Cannot run program "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\Ahmed\PycharmProjects\mypython"): CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation".

Comment: Looks like you don't have the right to run the python exe, did you install python as admin, and try running pyCharm as normal user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation,

this line indicates that it should be run by administrator of the computer, 
try running it via admin account or with admin rights